# How to create complex alias (start Ember, start Rails, and change directory) in Ubuntu 20.10.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, gnome-terminal, bash-alias

I'd like to use an alias to start my Rails/Ember app, open a new terminal tab and cd into the Ember directory. I use Ubuntu 20.10.4 and the default Terminal. This is what i have so far:

```
alias myproject='cd ~/code/myproject-rails && rails s & cd ~/code/myproject-ember && ember s & gnome-terminal --tab --active && cd ~/code/myproject-ember'
```

This is partially working: Both `rails s` and `ember s` do work and I can open the app in the browser. A new tab opens as well, but in my home directory. According to the [man pages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/gnome-terminal-1.html), the `--active` should "set the last specified tab as the active one in its window", but `cd` is not executed (in this tab).

What is wrong here? When I use `gnome-terminal --tab -e "cd ~/code/myproject-ember"` instead, there's an error message *No such file or directory*.

Comment: There is no such thing as `20.1.x` - KEEP the `0` - it is vital info regardless of what you believe.

Comment: Any believes did not play a role when writing the title (I was just not aware of Ubuntu's version numbering), but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [*In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

Alias is a purely textual replacement. Your alias injects so much code it would be more elegant if `myproject` was a function. This is a side "issue". You can stick to the alias if you want.

The main issue is you're expecting `cd ~/code/myproject-ember` to work in the newly opened tab. When your alias replaces `myproject` with

```
… gnome-terminal --tab --active && cd ~/code/myproject-ember
```

and this code is executed, the fact that `gnome-terminal` is executed will not inject the next command (`cd ~/code/myproject-ember`) into a command line *there*. `cd` will be executed in the current shell after this particular `gnome-terminal` process exits successfully. The whole snippet is similar to:

```
… true && cd …
```

and there's no reason why this `cd` should be performed anywhere else than in the shell that executes the whole command.

Your attempt with `gnome-terminal --tab -e "cd ~/code/myproject-ember"` fails because:

- `~` is never expanded. I understand the tilde is single-quoted when you define the alias. Then after the alias expansion it's [double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/108618). Then `gnome-terminal` receives the string `cd ~/code/myproject-ember`, splits it to words (without expanding the tilde) and tries to run the resulting command, but not in a shell (that could otherwise finally expand the tilde).
- Running `cd` this way makes no sense. `cd …` is executed not in a shell; this requires a [separate `cd` executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/108618), you may or may not have it in your OS. Even if you had it and even if the tilde was expanded, `gnome-terminal` would execute `cd` that would do its pointless job (change its own directory) and exit; and there would be nothing more to do in this tab.

The right way to make `gnome-terminal` start an interactive shell in some directory is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/75223/693277):

> ```
> gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir
> ```

Similarly as before, `gnome-terminal` won't expand `~` if it gets it after `--working-directory=`. Better use `$HOME` and and make sure it's expanded by your current shell. If you choose to use an alias, it may be:

```
alias myproject='cd ~/code/myproject-rails && rails s & cd ~/code/myproject-ember && ember s & gnome-terminal --tab --active "--working-directory=$HOME/code/myproject-ember"'
```

In this case `$HOME` will be expanded after each alias expansion.

As I said, IMO a function would be more elegant:

```sh
unalias myproject
myproject () {
   cd ~/code/myproject-rails && rails s &
   cd ~/code/myproject-ember && ember s &
   gnome-terminal --tab --active "--working-directory=$HOME/code/myproject-ember"
}
```

Note `rails` and `ember` will become jobs in the *old* shell. I don't know what they are but *maybe* you'd like to have them as jobs in the new shell. It can be done but I won't elaborate here. (If you need it and don't find a solution, ask a separate question.)

Comment: You might have luck with using the `-i` and `--rcfile` options to bash to launch the  jobs in the new shell. `man bash` followed by typing `/^INVOCATION` will bring you to the part of the manual page that explains this and other available options.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. This is a web development project and `rails s` and `ember s` start servers, it's fine for these jobs to remain in the old shell.